# linked lists versus form library

Tags: 2013

I need three linked lists but it seems that for me can be better to create an infopath form, what are the disadvantages or advantages of using one or another?

I need to access via CSOM or JSOM the items, is it possible with form libraries documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option:
1. create webpart pages and add list in web part zones. Then send connection to another webpart
http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4

Second option:
1. Use form library again put in webpart zone in webpart pages.

Hope any helps